# Are there any legal restrictions on busking in Mexico City?

Tags: legal, work, permits, mexico-city, busking

My nomadic sister is visiting me in Mexico City for a couple of weeks.  Her normal mode of travel involves [busking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busking) (playing music and/or singing in the streets) for money. She wants to do this in Mexico City.  Can she do this with a standard tourist visa? Are there any other legal restrictions on this?  Is a permit needed? Are there any places where it's not permitted?

Note: I realize Mexicans do this all the time, and I would be surprised if they all have permits, but I would not be surprised if they pay off an enforcement officer if they are ever challenged. As my sister doesn't speak Spanish, this could be a complicated matter, so naturally she prefers to operate above board if possible.

Comment: Not sure this is on-topic here..

Comment: @MeNoTalk: At minimum, whether it's permitted on a tourist visa should be on-topic (and I have now explicitly spelled out that question).

Comment: I think this is a great question and absolutely on-topic. I've met a few people busking around the world and wish I could do it one day. I have to say I've seen the Aztec dancers in and behind the Zocalo getting hassled by the police multiple times while they're busking. Though there is a possibility that some people might operate on a blurry line between busking and scamming none of these guys ever tried to scam me. Haven't been there for a few years now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recent report [compared busking in cities around the world](http://www.independent.ie/entertainment/music/dublin-named-third-best-city-in-the-world-for-buskers-30308958.html), finding Dublin to be the most receptive to buskers.

Mexico City, however, not so much:

> Mexico City was named the least encouraging city in the report, where
>   busking is illegal and could lead to imprisonment.

So based on that, I'd very much recommend that they do NOT attempt busking in Mexico.